# Slow loading of images from amazon s3 and cloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using amazon s3 services for hosting images. I have allot of images on my website.
I am also using CloudFront Distributions as cdn.
Image url's are fine.

But my images are still loading slowly as compared to some other top and competitors website.

Is there any way load images more fast?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you located? Where is your bucket located? Have you used the Network console in your browser to accurately measure the time? Have you tried it via different networks and different browsers? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details of how you have measured the speeds.

Comment: Can you privide a link to the site in question?  Have you enabled http/2 on the CloudFront distribution?

Answer (score 0):

There could be numerous of other problems with images:

- Loading too many images on the page. Make sure that you have lazy loading of your images that are not visible on initial render.
- Using wrong size of images. This can be fixed by resizing images to correct size. Also, do not forget about responsive images. You can read more about them [here](http://responsiveimages.org)
- Using next generation formats. For instance, look at using [WEBP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) for Chrome browser and [JPEG2000](https://jpeg.org/jpeg2000/) for Safari.

You can use [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) tool to test your website on all problems listed above.

Also, it might be worth to consider using specialized CDN for images like [pixboost.com](https://pixboost.com).

Answer (score 0):

Using a CDN like Cloudfront is the first step towards accelerating images. It addresses the challenges of Global distribution (your website is hosted in Europe but you have visitors from Australia => images will load from Cloudfront's node in Australia and be obviously faster than traveling from Europe). Also, it helps absorbing traffic peaks, for example during sales, Christmas, ...

**To go further with image acceleration**, you need to work on the images themselves and focus on 2 things:

1. resize the images to the target size (thumbnail, preview, full size, ...) and have different sizes for different screen sizes.
2. use image compression algorithms to "shrink" your images. You can use JPEG compression or alternative image formats like WebP, JPEG 2000, JPEG XR, ... These formats usually perform (shrink) better JPEG, however they come a big limitation: they are only supported by specific browser. Check caniuse.com for Browser support information: https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp

Bottom line, you will end up needing **15-20 versions of the same image** to get the maximum optimisation across all browsers, device screen sizes, use cases, ...

There are multiple ways for automating this, for example by using [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It's a great lib, but it requires coding and maintenance as it evolves quite dynamically.

Another option, is to use a Cloud-based image acceleration and delivery service. These services usually bundle image resizing and CDN delivery together and probably get you better CDN pricing as they negotiate big contracts with multiple CDN vendors.

We use https://cloudimage.io, but there are other great tools out there. Google is your best friend :).

Good luck with accelerating your page, faster images will definitely have a great impact.